# How to redirect to a dynamic external URL in Angular universal?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-universal

I'm using angular(7) universal and i need to redirect user to an external url which i get from a web api. the problem is there is no window object in angular universal (i need the search engine bots to be redirected - meaning it is most important in server side)
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a more detailed answer after @MBDev answer here is how you can set the meta tag grammatically

```
constructor(private _meta: Meta){}
redirect(){
   this._meta.addTag({ 'http-Equiv': 'refresh', content: '0; '+this.redirectUrl });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following html header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://mywebsite.test/" />
```